# I want to make vhdl divider

Tags: variables, integer, vhdl, divider

i'm now using FPGA spartan3,

i want to calculate 'result' which is represented below formula.
and the 'result' should be returned as integer type. So i set up all the variables with integer type but it doesn't work.

```
    result <=((a*b*7894*7)/(w*temp_constant));
```

i've set a,b,c,w,temp_constant as variables

```
    variable a : integer range 0 to 99;
    variable b : integer range 0 to 9999;
    variable w : integer range 0 to 200;
    variable temp_constant : integer range 0 to 99;
```

but the operator '/' doesn't work at this synthesis. the error msg was
'Operator '/' must have constant operands or first operand must be power of 2"'

Comment: Wow, that quite a complex calculation. Even if you get it to synthesize, it will require a lot of resources and have a very long delay. Don't expect high clock frequencies. If you come from software: you cannot program an FPGA like a microcontroller. You need to implement pipelining and such.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is almost (see the note below) 100% clear: divisions are not supported by your synthesis tool, except with constant operands (the result is computed by the synthesizer in the constant propagation phase) or with divisors that are powers of 2 (the division is a simple right shift).

One possible reason for this limitation of your synthesis tool is that there are many of ways to compute integer divisions in hardware and typing just `/` in a VHDL code is not enough to chose among them. There may be other reasons.

In your case where operands are not constants, and the divisor is not a power of 2, you must design this divider yourself at a lower level. If you have no idea about hardware implementations of integer dividers you will have to search a bit. This is a very classical topic, it should be easy to find good resources. Just a hint: pre-computing all inverses in fixed point representation, storing them in a read-only memory and using multiplications instead of divisions is an option.

Note: I find the error message you got (*first operand must be power of 2*) a bit surprising. Unless the term *first operand* is supposed to designate the divisor, which is not that common, it is probably a bug and the correct error message should be: *second operand must be power of 2*. Or, even better: *divisor must be power of 2*.

Comment: a,b,w,temp_constant are inputs who were given by dipswitch, so they're keep changing. how can i make them as a fixed point???

Comment: You don't *make then fixed point*. You compute `w*temp_constant`and use the result as the address of a read-only memory (ROM). The ROM content is such that at address `X` you find the inverse of `X`, multiplied by a constant power of 2 and rounded to the nearest integer. Multiply the value read from the ROM (`2**N/(w*temp_constant`) by `a*b*7894*7`, drop the N LSBs and you are (almost) done.

Comment: As your inputs come from switches you will have a very low throughput. One division per second would be sufficient. So, the best implementation is probably not the ROM-based one. Look at serial dividers and select the smallest one. Same for your multipliers: use only one and select a small serial-parallel architecture. The computation will take tens or even hundreds of clock cycles but it will still be fast enough.